# ThinkPad with Debian is hot

Tags: thinkpad, temperature, debian-wheezy

I am using a ThinkPad X201 with Debian (Wheezy) and LXDE. The laptop is very hot even without heavy load. Now, the load of CPU with a top command: load average: 0.04, 0.12, 0.13, But the temperature is 55<sup>o</sup> C. I opened the laptop and checked the fan. It is not so dirty. I am sure that there is no any large software running. Can anyone can help me to fix it?

The output of sensors in my system is:

```
 acpitz-virtual-0
 Adapter: Virtual device
 temp1:        +54.0°C  (crit = +100.0°C)

 coretemp-isa-0000
 Adapter: ISA adapter
 Core 0:       +51.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
 Core 2:       +48.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)

 thinkpad-isa-0000
 Adapter: ISA adapter
 fan1:        3265 RPM
 temp1:        +54.0°C  
 temp2:         +0.0°C  
 temp3:         +0.0°C  
 temp4:         +0.0°C  
 temp5:         +0.0°C  
 temp6:         +0.0°C  
 temp7:         +0.0°C  
 temp8:         +0.0°C
```

This is the lowest temperature under normal use.

Comment: OK,perfect, your temperatures are half what would be considered a dangerous temperature. Everything is fine, your computer is not hot, it is running at a very normal temperature. Everything is OK :)

Comment: While it's true that those temperatures are fine, I'm wondering if the whole Intel Speed Step thing is working for you.  This would also explain some of your battery drain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

55 is not that hot, sounds fine to me actually. 55 is about the lowest temperature I *ever* see on my Dell.

One way of checking what the critical (the dangerous) temperature is for your CPU is `sensors` (the output shown is what I get on my Dell with an i7 processor):

- First, install it and detect available sensors

  ```
  $ sudo apt-get install sensors
  $ sudo sensors-detect
  ```
- Then run it

  ```
  $ sensors
  coretemp-isa-0000
  Adapter: ISA adapter
  Core 0:       +56.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
  Core 2:       +55.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)

  i8k-virtual-0
  Adapter: Virtual device
  Right Fan:   87240 RPM
  CPU:          +54.0°C
  ```

  That tells me that the CPU is considered hot after 95 degrees and will shutdown to avoid damage at 105, that's twice what you're experiencing.

Comment: @HXGuo please add the output to your question ([edit] it) not to the comments.

Comment: I have updated my question. Is the temperature not hot? The battery of my laptop only can use in 30 min.

Comment: @HXGuo no the temperatures are not hot, not even a little bit. If the battery only lasts for 30 mins, that is a different problem. PLease post a new question about that.